# How to hide folder in SSRS Report Builder?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

When I click File -> Open on Report Builder, I can see a list of folders under Report Server Home root folder. But I don't want end-user to see any of the folders under root unless I grant them access.

I tried hiding and removing permission on the folders but they are still visible in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the "Hide in list View" in the folder properties This will hide the folder from users. Admins can still see the folder in the "Show details" view but it will be greyed out to indicate it is hidden

Answer (score -1):

1. In your SQL Reporting Services Management Console
2. Select '**Manage**' on the report you wish to hide in the 'Details View'.
3. Select '**Properties**' in the management window.
4. Check the '**Hide in title view**' checkbox located below the Name and Description text boxes.